# Audio source in Safari causes beep noise at song start

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, noise

I'm building a small web app based on this [audio visualizer](https://github.com/michaelbromley/soundcloud-visualizer) which uses the Web Audio API and the SoundCloud API. In Chrome and Firefox, everything is working fine, but sometimes(!) Safari gives me a strange short beep sound at song start, especially when I reload my page while there is already a song playing.

On the GitHub page I referred to is also a demo link, so you can examine that a bit better.

The problem occurs on both the original project and my modified version. I now found that when I remove `player.play()` in `line 75, app.js` the beep is gone (including all the song sound of course.. :D ). However, I think that that line is responsible for my problem (the player variable refers to the html `<audio>`-Tag btw..). Also, adding additional nodes to e.g. mute the audio source did not fix the issue.

**I found a workaround**, but I'm not sure if that will always work: Setting `player.muted = true;` and adding a short timeout which resets it to false again after a short time seems to fix the issue (even if it does look horrible).

I did not find any similar question, but maybe you can point me somewhere or help me, thanks

Comment: OK, setting player.muted true did also not work some times

Comment: I am having similar issues; please report back if you found a solution